# HTML hidden not submitting

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net

I have been developing a personal project for a couple of weeks now, and over the past week something changed and the HTML Hidden helper function stopped submitting for some reason and I can't find out why.

Here is the view.

```
@model GolfTracker.ViewModels.NewRoundViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "NewRound";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>New Round</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Finish", "Rounds"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Select course:</p>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Round.Course, new SelectList(Model.Courses), "Select course", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "courseDropdown" })
    </div>
    <table class="table-dark" id="scorecard" style="text-align: center; border: 2px solid #00bc8c; table-layout: fixed">
        <thead class="table-secondary">
            <th style="vertical-align: middle; padding: 0px; border: 0px">
                #
            </th>
            @for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
            {
                <th style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0px; border: 0px" width="4.5%">
                    <div>
                        @i
                    </div>
                </th>
            }
            <th style="padding: 0px; border: 0px">
                Total
            </th>
        </thead>
        <tr class="table-secondary">
            <td style="vertical-align: middle">
                Par
            </td>
            @for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
            {
                <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; vertical-align: middle">
                    <div id="hole-@i-par">

                    </div>
                </td>
            }
            <td>
                <div id="par-sum">

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-secondary">
            <td style="vertical-align: middle">
                Yardage
            </td>
            @for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
            {
                <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
                    <div id="hole-@i-yardage">

                    </div>
                </td>
            }
            <td id="yard-sum"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="scores-array" class="table-secondary">
            <td style="vertical-align: middle">
                Score
            </td>
            @for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
            {
                Model.Round.Scores.Add(new GolfTracker.Models.HoleScore()
                {
                    Score = 0
                });
                <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;" align="center">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Round.Scores[i - 1].Score, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "tb-h" + i, @style = "padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; text-align: center; display: block" })
                </td>
            }
            <td id="score-sum"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="putts-array" class="table-secondary">
            <td style="vertical-align: middle">
                Putts
            </td>
            @for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
            {
            <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;" align="center">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Round.Scores[i - 1].Putts, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "tb-p" + i, @style = "padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; text-align: center; display: block" })
            </td>
            }
            <td id="putts-sum"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="uad-array" class="table-secondary">
            <td style="vertical-align: middle">
                Up-and-Down
            </td>
            @for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
            {
                <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Round.Scores[i - 1].UAD, new { @class = "form-check-input", @id = "chb-uad" + i, @style = "margin: 0px; position: relative; width: 20px; height: 20px;" })
                </td>
            }
            <td id="uad-sum"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="ss-array" class="table-secondary">
            <td style="vertical-align: middle">
                Sand Save
            </td>
            @for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
            {
                <td style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Round.Scores[i - 1].SS, new { @class = "form-check-input", @id = "chb-ss" + i, @style = "margin: 0px; position: relative; width: 20px; height: 20px;" })
                </td>
            }
            <td id="ss-sum"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Round.Date)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Round.Date, "{0:d MMM yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", Type = "date" })
    </div>
    @Html.Hidden("numHoles", Model.Round.Holes)
    @Html.Hidden("score", Model.Round.Score)
    @Html.Hidden("putts", Model.Round.Putts)
    @Html.Hidden("uad", Model.Round.UAD)
    @Html.Hidden("ss", Model.Round.SS)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Round.Fairways)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Round.Fairways, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Round.GIR)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Round.GIR, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="save">Save</button>
}
```

Here are the scripts. By the time the user presses the save button, all the data is already calculated and saved to their respective elements. The hidden inputs do indeed have the data, but they don't send it back to the model on submit.

Edit: I am aware there are multiple repeated scripts that could be created through using a loop, but I tried that and it didn't work because each iteration kept using the final index rather than the correct one. I had to resort to declaring them manually.

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#courseDropdown").change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/api/coursesapi/" + $(this).val(),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (course) {
                        $("#scorecard").show();
                        if (course != null) {
                            var yardSum = 0;
                            var holeYardage;
                            var holePar;
                            for (var i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
                                holeYardage = document.getElementById("hole-" + i + "-yardage");
                                holePar = document.getElementById("hole-" + i + "-par");
                                holeYardage.innerText = course.Holes[i - 1].Length;
                                holePar.innerText = course.Holes[i - 1].Par;
                                yardSum += course.Holes[i - 1].Length;
                            }
                            document.getElementById("par-sum").innerText = course.Par;
                            document.getElementById("yard-sum").innerText = yardSum;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            $("#save").click(function () {
                console.log("numHoles: " + $("#numHoles").val());
                console.log("score: " + $("#score").val());
                console.log("putts: " + $("#putts").val());
                console.log("uad: " + $("#uad").val());
                console.log("ss: " + $("#ss").val());
            });

            $("#scores-array").change(function () {
                var score;
                var sum = 0;
                var numHoles = 0;
                for (var i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
                    if (parseInt($("#tb-h" + i).val()) > 0) {
                        numHoles++;
                    }
                    score = $("#tb-h" + i);
                    sum += parseInt(score.val());
                }
                document.getElementById("score-sum").innerText = sum;
                $("#score").val(sum);
                $("#numHoles").val(numHoles);
            });

            $("#putts-array").change(function () {
                var putts;
                var sum = 0;
                for (var i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
                    putts = $("#tb-p" + i);
                    sum += parseInt(putts.val());
                }
                document.getElementById("putts-sum").innerText = sum;
                $("#putts").val(sum);
            });

            $("#uad-array").change(uadEval);

            $("#ss-array").change(function () {
                var sum = 0;
                for (var i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
                    if ($("#chb-ss" + i).is(":checked")) {
                        sum++;
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById("ss-sum").innerText = sum;
                $("#ss").val(sum);
            });

            $("#chb-ss1").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss1").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad1").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad1").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad1").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad1").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss2").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss2").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad2").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad2").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad2").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad2").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss3").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss3").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad3").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad3").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad3").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad3").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss4").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss4").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad4").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad4").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad4").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad4").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss5").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss5").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad5").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad5").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad5").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad5").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss6").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss6").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad6").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad6").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad6").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad6").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss7").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss7").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad7").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad7").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad7").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad7").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss8").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss8").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad8").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad8").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad8").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad8").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss9").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss9").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad9").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad9").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad9").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad9").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss10").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss10").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad10").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad10").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad10").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad10").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss11").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss11").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad11").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad11").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad11").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad11").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss12").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss12").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad12").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad12").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad12").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad12").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss13").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss13").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad13").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad13").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad13").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad13").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss14").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss14").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad14").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad14").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad14").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad14").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss15").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss15").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad15").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad15").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad15").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad15").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss16").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss16").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad16").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad16").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad16").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad16").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });
            
            $("#chb-ss17").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss17").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad17").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad17").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad17").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad17").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            $("#chb-ss18").change(function () {
                if ($("#chb-ss18").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#chb-uad18").prop("checked", true);
                    $("#chb-uad18").prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#chb-uad18").prop("checked", false);
                    $("#chb-uad18").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                uadEval();
            });

            function uadEval() {
                var sum = 0;
                for (var i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
                    if ($("#chb-uad" + i).is(":checked")) {
                        sum++;
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById("uad-sum").innerText = sum;
                $("#uad").val(sum);
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: FYI: When you see yourself copy and pasting the same thing over and over again and changing a couple of characters, you need to say to yourself.... there has to be a better way.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing it in a loop using the index, but for some reason that never worked. I think it kept using the index the loop ended on for all of them. I didn't want to copy and paste them, but that was the only thing that worked.

Comment: Take out everything except 1 hidden field. Does it work? Start putting things back in until it breaks. Also, bring up Fiddler. Is the value of the hidden field being shipped? If the hidden field is there in the form, it will be shipped.

Comment: @Jonathan I just tried that and it still doesn't work. I did however do more experimentation and found that when I add a test variable to the viewmodel itself, it gets updated by the hidden field, whereas if I add a test variable to a Round or Course model it fails. I think it might have something to do with those models.

I should add that the .click() for the "#save" used to be a .submit(), but that stopped working at the same time the hidden fields stopped working. I wouldn't be surprised if the cause is related.

Comment: @Jonathan I just saw the http request through Fiddler and it is actually sending the data, which is weird because I have output the data on the receiving end and it's still 0s. There must be something up with the viewmodel. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jonathan I have narrowed down the problem. It's an issue with the hidden field model binding. Apparently something changed when I updated the model last week. Still no clue what it could be.

Comment: If the data is going through, bit it's null when it's deserialized, then the model binder is having difficulty translating it. Name isn't exactly the same, or type isn't the same... Something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. For some reason the HTML hidden() helper functions did not have the correct names for the model binding. I think it worked before because the structure of the viewmodel was different, and when I updated the viewmodel the "name" attributes of the hidden fields weren't pointing to valid variables anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do the trick with jquery serialize by unhidden all fields before you getting the value and hide it back after everything complete.